# How can Jesus saw Nathanael in John1:48 when he was not at that place?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, protestantism, gospel-of-john

Jesus said no servant is greater than his master. Jesus even showed to Apostles that he can walk on water but only Peter had enough courage to follow although his faith was not yet enough.

Eastern Tradition on the Dormition of Mary speaks of many translocation via angels intervention to carry the Apostles from far away places to the place where the Panagia was resting waiting for all the presence of the Apostles.

Apostle Philip had a narrated story of translocation in Acts8:39-40.No wonder Jesus chose him to be a witness when he first displayed his power to know Nathanael location eventhough he knew Jesus was at a different place.

in John gospel, the mystery how Jesus knew the location of Nathanael must have been pondered by the chosen Apostles early in Jesus ministry.

> Jesus answered, "I saw you while you were still under the fig tree before Philip called you." (John 1:48)

The word " I saw you" is the mysterious word, either Jesus saw him in a vision or with his own physical eyes.

It would seems that Jesus in order to find the whereabouts of His chosen apostles had been bilocating.

Who among Bible believing christians interpret this event as bilocation and not just a mere visions?If none,  I am open for Catholicism interpretation who can cite credible connections to biliocation phenomena.

Comment: I think you mean John 1:48.   I can see  no reason to interpret this as anything other than that Jesus had passed within sight of the fig tree earlier in the day and had seen Nathaniel under it,  but perhaps somebody will know differently.

Comment: @davidiol thanks for correcting the verse, but dont you think if Jesus saw earlier Nathanael in the fig tree, then why Jesus did not proceed to call him at that moment?

Comment: Asking what "Christians" believe is way too broad.

Comment: @itzsophia'svlogs   The question why Jesus didn't call Nathanael when He saw him, would also apply if He was bi-locating, why He didn't speak. But we see in the dialogue between Phillip and Nathanael that Nathanael was not initially well-disposed to Jesus. It took the persuasion of Philip, someone Nathanael was perhaps friendly with, to persuade Nathanael  to change his initial prejudice against anybody from Nazareth.

Comment: @davidiol Perhaps Jesus wanted to show his power to the chosen Apostles that he  can know their location and read their hearts. Without Jesus showing his power how can they believe and leave everything behind?

Comment: @curiousdanii first you put the question on hold. Then I revised it to be more specific to accommodate your comment but you still move to closed this question. im amaze, i mean perplexed at your wisdom. How can this be opinion based when Im asking if there are bible believing Christians who interpret this as bilocation?

Answer (score 5):

John 1:48 does not imply bilocation any more than any other prophet's visions indicate bilocation.  For example:

- Daniel had dreams/visions about events at the Ulai canal (Dan 8)
- Ezekiel had visions about heaven and the exiles in Jerusalem
- John saw things about heaven as well
- Paul records a vision about the third heaven (2 Cor 12:1-6)
- Samuel records many events about that he saw, eg, about Saul, 1 Sam 10:1-9.

There are many more examples.  None of these is any evidence of bilocation - merely a vision given by God without any need for bilocation.

Would not supernatural "insight" by Jesus be a more natural explanation of John 1:48 than mystical, un-evidenced bilocation?

Comment: Its hard to consider this as vision as it was early in the day and Jesus is going around looking for his chosen apostle. Philip was called to follow him,  how can Philip go separate ways immediately, if Jesus not ask him to go to the fig three and ask Nathsnael to come with him. And Philip cannot choose Nathanael as Apostle on his own initiative without Jesus instructing him.

Comment: There are no restrictions on when a vision might happen. Indeed there is no need that a vision of something happens at the same time as the thing seen. Visions can be of events in the past or the future. So it is perfectly possible that Jesus saw Nathaniel in a vision.

Comment: @DJClayworth do you agree that vision or dreams entails significant messages or future events while John1:48 has no messages its simply determine the current location of Nathanael.Jesus instructed Philip to call Nathanael but Philip had no clue about his location.Im not convince of Mac's Musing attributing this to a vision or dreams as Jesus is clearly awake and walking on early day looking for the whereabouts of his chosen apostle.

Comment: Visions often occur while awake. And as I say, the vision may have happened previously, not necessarily at the time of the narration.

Comment: @DJClayworth sorry but I am not convince this is a vision,  as this is an event where Jesus is looking around to find the whereabouts of his chosen apostle at present time. Remember this happened after Andrew & Peter had followed Jesus,  and the next day Jesus was with them and added Philip early on the day.The Wisdom of Jesus as he was anointed already heard the voice of Nathanael praying and bilocated while Jesus was with Philip, Andrew and Peter.(Wisdom1:7 )

Comment: You asked how Christians interpret this event, and Mac correctly describes how Christians interpret it. Discussion is frowned on in comments. You are free to interpret differently.

Comment: @DJClayworth the  cited verses on the  answer is a visions of future event and in no way resembles John1:48 as it speaks of present time and only deals with locating Nathanael whereabout.Do you think the cited verses on the answer gave a clear comparison?